# How to execute an update query in spark through JDBC

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jdbc

I would like to perform all dml operations on the sqlserver data in spark using JDBC ,but I'm facing issues while executing UPDATE query.
Below is the code used for obtaining connection and the queries used for execution,along with the exception got while executing UPDATE query.
Any help or any pointers as to how to get over this issue will be of great help.
Thanks in advance.

```
val jdbcDbTable = "dbName"

val jdbcSqlConnStr = "jdbc:sqlserver://xxxx:portno;" + "user=xx;password=xxx;"
val jdbcDF = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc")
  .options(Map("driver" -> "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
               "url" -> jdbcSqlConnStr,
               "dbtable" -> jdbcDbTable))
  .load()
jdbcDF.registerTempTable("customer1")

val cust = sqlContext.sql("Select * from customer1")
cust.show()
```

The issue is ,that the select * statement returns proper results ,but when I do execute an update statement like this :

```
val upd = sqlContext.sql("update customer1  set C_NAME='newcustomer' " +
        " where C_CustKey=1471774")
upd.show()
```

I get error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
mismatched input 'update' expecting {'(', 'SELECT', 'FROM', 'ADD', 'DESC', 'WITH', 'VALUES', 'CREATE', 'TABLE', 'INSERT', 'DELETE', 'DESCRIBE', 'EXPLAIN', 'SHOW', 'USE', 'DROP', 'ALTER', 'MAP', 'SET', 'RESET', 'START', 'COMMIT', 'ROLLBACK', 'REDUCE', 'REFRESH', 'CLEAR', 'CACHE', 'UNCACHE', 'DFS', 'TRUNCATE', 'ANALYZE', 'LIST', 'REVOKE', 'GRANT', 'LOCK', 'UNLOCK', 'MSCK', 'EXPORT', 'IMPORT', 'LOAD'}(line 1, pos 0)

== SQL ==
update customer1  set C_NAME='newcustomer'  where C_CustKey=1471774
^^^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not updating a table over JDBC , you are trying to update a spark catalog table. Spark doesn't support update statements.

You can execute the query over a JDBC connection (using Spark or Plain JDBC ) and then fetch back the dataframe.